# Is this possible to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

how can I solve the following equation

```
x[r_]=-16*(0.189*Log[3.35-r]-0.0861*Log[-1.078+r]-0.103*Log[4.42+r])
```

and obtain r[x]?

Comment: Knowing `x[r]` you could use `InverseFunction`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could define the inverse function "by hand":

```
rx[x_?NumericQ] := r /. NSolve[{x == -16*(0.189*Log[3.35 - r] - 0.0861*Log[-1.078 + r] - 0.103*Log[4.42 + r])}, r, Reals][[1]]
```

and check it

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[{r, -16*(0.189*Log[3.35 - r] - 0.0861*Log[-1.078 + r] -0.103*Log[4.42 + r])}, {r, 0, 3}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {r, x}],
Graphics[Point[Table[{rx[x], x}, {x, -5, 5, .25}]]]}]
```

Alternatively you can use `InverseFunction`:

```
ri = InverseFunction[Function[{r}, -16*(0.189*Log[3.35 - r] - 0.0861*Log[-1.078 + r] -0.103*Log[4.42 + r])]]
ParametricPlot[{ri[x], x}, {x, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]